# How to hide index column of DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How can I hide the first column of my DataTable which contains indexes of my rows?

I already tried `bSortClasses: false` and `orderClasses: false`, but it didn't work.

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: simply remove corresponding column definition from `columns`/`columnDefs` section of your options

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
    columnDefs: [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 0 }
    ],
```